# Mansory framework layout - whitespace issue

Tags: html, css

Im using http://masonry.desandro.com to create nice looking grid.

However, it's causing some whitespace when the image is wide or long.

In brief, card width is 23%, wide and long cards are 48% and margin is 1% for both of them. Box-sizing is enabled

I also tried to set up height manually, but it doesn't help much.

[image]

You can also check it live on
http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/personal.html

Pen is available also, however it differs from one on the site visually 
http://codepen.io/dpmango/pen/JbVPoy

```
.mansory-grid
  a(href="#modalPeopleOne").popup-with-zoom-anim.personal__card.personal__card--huge
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/frank_1.jpg").img-fluid

  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--no-hover
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/personal_1.jpg").img-fluid

  a(href="#").personal__card
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/13.jpg").img-fluid

  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--wide
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/4.jpg").img-fluid

  a(href="#").personal__card
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/10.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--no-hover.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/personal_2.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--long
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/2.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--wide
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/5.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--no-hover
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/personal_3.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--long.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/6.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/11.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/12.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--no-hover.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/personal_4.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/1.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/9.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--long
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/7.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.personal__card--wide
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/3.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/14.jpg").img-fluid
  a(href="#").personal__card.mt30
    img(src="http://dpmango.github.io/doctor-frank/dist/images/people/8.jpg").img-fluid
```

Css code

```
.mansory-grid
  &:after
    display: block
    clear: both
    content: ' '

    .personal__card
      display: block
      position: relative
      float: left
      width: 23%
      margin: 1%
      overflow: hidden
      &:after
        display: block
        position: absolute
        top: 0
        left: 0
        right: 0
        bottom: 0
        content: ' '
        opacity: 0
        z-index: 1
        transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out
        background: black
      &:hover
        &:after
          opacity: .6

      &--no-hover
        cursor: default
        &:hover
          &:after
            opacity: 0
          .personal__card__name
            opacity: 0
          .personal__card__status
            opacity: 0

      &--huge
        width: 48%

      &--wide
        width: 48%
```

Comment: Not sure, probably not related to problem, but you are closing html tag before body tag is opened? Also, did you selected right items in masonry options? http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#itemselector It seems to me that masonry js isn't applied at all...

Comment: On your website masonry isn't being applied (the plugin isn't picking up) and on your codepen it is being applied